# Using django for non http requests

Tags: python, django, tcp

Can I use django to handle **non** http-requests and responses? I have a django web application serving up webpages, and I would like to use it to also communicate with other devices (hand-held gps sending in status reports and receiving ack) over tcp, but django reports that the requests are "

```
code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type".

    [28/Sep/2015 15:14:26] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('[V1.0.0,244565434376396,1,abcd,2015-09-28')
    [28/Sep/2015 15:14:26] "[V1.0.0,244565434376396,1,abcd,2015-09-28 14:14:12,1-2,865456543459367,2,T1]" 400 -
```

The message from the device is sent as text over tcp with no http parameters at all.

I haven't found any information on how to do this with django, but it would make my life easier if it was possible.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is most likely your webserver (apache?) that serves the website, since that is programmed to accept HTTP(s) connections. I'm quite sure that it would give you problems when you want to accept non HTTP connections. You would probably need to open your own socket to accept such connection. Not sure how that would work with django though as it typically expects http requests.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I have to implement something outside of django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not that I know of.*

Django is a web framework, so it's designed around a certain **paradigm** if not a certain *protocol*.

The design is *heavily* informed - if not by HTTP - by the notions of **URL**, request, a stateless protocol, et cetera.

If the template system and the routing system were taken away you would be left with **a glorified ORM** and some useless bits of code.

However, unless you are dealing with existing devices with their own protocol, you *can* use Django to **build a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service** to successfully exchange information with something other than bipeds in front of a web browser.

[This article on Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069) is very informative.

[Django REST](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), although by no means necessary, can help you.

If you are really stuck with legacy devices and protocols, you *could* write **an adapter/proxy** that would receive your devices' requests and translate them to RESTful calls, *if* you protocol looks *enough* like HTTP semantically rather than syntactically (as in, if you just have to translate `QUUX aaa:bbb:ccc:` to `GET xx/yy/zz`).

If it does not share the slightest bit of HTTP's semantics, I'd say Django can't help you much.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but unfortunately REST won't work, since I can't touch the devices. I kinda figured I was out of luck with this, since I found no information about non http requests.

Comment: @Svante: as I mentioned above, you *could* consider writing an adapter to a RESTful service. You might want to weight the pros and cons. Take this *cum grano salis*, but the fact that you would consider to use Django makes me suspect your protocol is... webb-ish enough.

Comment: Absolutely! I think that this might be the best way. I am currently looking at a solution with SocketServer that I found [Django TCP socket communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307916/django-tcp-socket-communication) for forwarding requests to the main application.

Comment: @Svante: just do note that the answer you linked proposes a *regular* Python script and then says "you can still import django's libraries and use django's ORM (DB) inside a SocketServer" - as I said before, you would end up using Django as a glorified ORM in an hackish script. Depending on your requirements, this might be a suboptimal/less extensible architectural solution. It may, of course, float your boat just fine. :)

Comment: Update: I ended up with writing a separate SocketServer script outside the django project (it is run by supervisor). The script listens for incoming traffic on a separate port, checks the incoming request, opens a url socket to the django project, django processes the request and returns a JsonResponse with the result over the url socket.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion that you can better handle non-http with other methods, but I do have a suggestion as to how to structure a Django app that *could* do it.  HTTP processing takes place in middleware and you could just make your app be on the top of that stack and either pre-empt other middlewares by returning the response instead of passing it down the stack or preparing a mock request to pass down to other handlers, grabbing the response on the way back to post-process it for your receiver.

This feels hacky and might require a bunch of un-orthodox tricks but that's how I would approach the problem as stated.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, that could work, I am at the moment looking at a solution using SocketServer, but I just might check your suggestion a bit closer as well :)